# Featured items won't stack in rioght hand columns

Tags: joomla3.0

My menu item "Home" points to a "featured article" which I have set with layout #leading articles =0, #intro articles=8, #columns =2.  Order of presentation on the page is oldest first.
The welcome text on the left is quite long and sits on the left column ok.  The next article is short as it has a read more break (like the other articles that follow) and sits on the right hand column fine.

But the next two articles hide down the bottom and across the page.  I really want to make them fill up the empty space below the article on the right.  There is a lot of space there as the article on the left is quite long.   see www.resbona.co.uk

Is what I'm trying to do possible?- I'm using Joomlashack Vintage template with Joomla 3 (latest).
And if so how to do?

Thanks for any help
Derek

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with basic Joomla Content Component without modifying code. What you can do to archive this is:

- Limit featured items count to 1
- Add Articles Category module to right column
- Set module articles ordering and filtering options to match your front page options

To archive the same using Joomla component only you will have to use [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) and create your own layout for featured items or override default.